# Tutorial по angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Нужно, чтобы было доходчиво и вкратце объяснялись все моменты, можно на английском.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

http://angular.ru/tutorial

чем не подходят?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://fastandfluid.com/publicdownloads/AngularJSIn60MinutesIsh_DanWahlin_May2013.pdf

Comment: Вот это, скорее всего, то что мне нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Понравиласть эта статья:

**Getting started with AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC**

- [Part One](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par)
- [Part Two](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806500/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-P)
- [Part Three](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/843044/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-The)

Answer (score 1):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/246881/

Вот такой есть ещё учебник на-русском :)

Answer (score 1):

Хорошая книга Туловский А "Руководство разработчика Angular"
Раньше [тут](http://mexalib.com/view/39694) можно было скачать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот интересный набор
[туториалов](https://www.codeschool.com/courses#all)

Answer (score 0):

[Отличный туториал](https://www.thinkful.com/learn/angularjs-tutorial-build-a-gmail-clone/), строим клон аля Gmail, для начинающих самое то.